# How to Convert String to Char and Integer in Java ?

Tags: java, string

I have the following :

1. String contain 5* ;
2. char opr ;
3. int data ;

I would like to store the 5 in the data and * in the opr

any idea how to do it ?
 as i know if the string contain only Integer then I will split and the parse it but in this case the String contain int and char

Input :

String input = 5* ;

I want the Output will be like this :

this.opr = *

this.data = 5

Comment: This question is *highly specific*. You should probably define the full use case of what you want. A regex along the lines of `([\\d]+)(.*)` will allow you to access in `Matcher` groups the number and the operand, but if there are other requirements then such a regex wouldn't work.

Comment: One way would be using `char opr = str.charAt(1);` `int data = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0,1));`. But something tells me that this may be too specific. If you need more general solution you need to describe more general example.

Comment: @Pshemo there is no specific code, i am trying to find out how to do it and you answer is perfect :) thanks a lot "dzięki"

Comment: If you're working with just this example, use String#substring.

Comment: @KevinO I have this case (input /output) and i wanted to get an idea how to solve it so no need to give more as i wanted to make it short and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve that (if you don't want to use *Regex*) is to do something like this:

```
String temp ="";
// read every char in the input String
for(char c: input.toCharArray()){
   // if it's a digit
   if(Character.isDigit(c)){
       temp +=c; // append it
   }
   else{ // at the end parse the temp String
        data = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        opr = c;
        break;
   }
}

//test
System.out.println("Input: " + input 
                    + "\t Data: " + data
                    + "\t Opr: " + opr);
```

**Test**

```
Input: 5*    Data: 5     Opr: *
Input: 123*  Data: 123   Opr: *
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the dubious assumption that the issue is parsing a `String` in the form of number followed by op, this code will achieve the desired result.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String input = "5*";
    int data = -1;
    String op = "";

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([\\d]+)[\\s]*(.*)");

    Matcher m = pat.matcher(input);
    if (m.matches() && m.groupCount() == 2) {
        data = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        op = m.group(2).trim();
    }
    System.out.printf("%2d with op %s%n", data, op);
}
```

Output:

> 5 with op *

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = 5*;
char[] splitted = input.toCharArray();
char opr = splitted[1];
int data = Character.getNumericValue(splitted[0]);
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowed upon in SO. Maybe give an explanation to your code?

Answer (score 0):

you may also try this with 3 different inputs as below. It will print 0 for incorrect DATA and blank for incorrect OPERAND.

```
    String  input       = "5*";
    //String  input       = "109/";
    //String  input       = "109b3*";


    int     data        = 0;
    char    opr         = ' ';
    int     len         = input.length();


    if  (   len > 1 ) {
        String  data_s  = input.substring(0, len - 1);

        try {
                data    = Integer.valueOf(data_s).intValue();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }

                opr     = input.substring(len - 1). charAt(0);
        if  (   opr    != '+' && opr != '-' && opr != '*' && opr != '/' ) {
                opr     = ' ';
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Input:" + input + " Data:" + data + " Opr:" + opr);
```